# Get a week ago from given date PHP

Tags: php, date, datetime

I have a monthly bill table that stored where customer need to pay the bill in `Y-m-d` format, i need to send an email notification a week before this due date. for example:

```
public function cronSendNotif($transaction){
  $dueDate = $transaction->getDueDate(); // 2019-08-03
  $weekAgo = $this->getWeekAgoDate($dueDate); // 2019-07-27

  $this->sendEmailNotification($transaction->getId(),$weekAgo);
}

private function getWeekAgoDate($dueDate){
   // how ??
}
```

how can i get the week ago date in `Y-m-d` format , if i have this given date in `Y-m-d` format?

Comment: use `DateTime` classes, load the date you want, subtract 1 week, echo format, profit! :D

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
private function getWeekAgoDate($dueDate){
  $weekAgo = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-7 days', strtotime($dueDate)));
  return $weekAgo;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using strtotime, you can simply add/subtract days, weeks etc. from a date. Example:

```
function getWeekAgoDate($dueDate){
   return date("Y-m-d", strtotime($dueDate . "-1 week"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also make use of the modify function.

```
$weekAgo = getWeekAgoDate($dueDate);
echo $weekAgo->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

function getWeekAgoDate(DateTime $dueDate){
   return $dueDate->modify("- 7 days");
}
```

Documentation: php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code - how could `+7 days` return a date that is one week ago? If you want to enforce the input variable, why not use type hints?

Comment: @NicoHaase my mistake, i realise it right after i posted the answer and edited it. It should be -.

This is the documentation: https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php

Comment: Please add all explanation to your answer, not to the comment section. And still, if you want to enforce that `$dueDate` has the proper type, you should type hint that argument